# Code terminates after single iteration in member function which is assigning values to pointer in loop

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I'm creating an abstract datatype. The code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class cArray
{
    int size;
    T* p;

public:
    cArray(int size)
    {
        this -> size = size;
        T* p = new T[size];
    }

    void setval(void)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cout << "enter value at index " << i << endl;
            // cin >> *(p+i);
            cin >> p[i];
        }
    }

    void disp(void)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cout << *(p+i) <<endl;
        }
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    cArray <float> obj(5);
    obj.setval();
    obj.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

where `setval` sets the values in the array and `disp` displays the elements in it.

However, the code terminates after single iteration in `setval`. I'm not sure how to fix this as pointer arithmetic in it seems correct. Kindly, suggest changes.

Comment: Unrelated: There is already a class `std::array`.  Drop the `using namespace std` or choose a different name.

Comment: Done. However, problem persist.

Comment: Think about the difference between the assignment `this -> size = size;` and the declaration `T* p = new T[size];`. Why did you do these in different ways?

Comment: `T* p = new T[size];` creates a new variable `p` and is not using the class member - increase your compiler warning level - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Ws4rzKdEW

Comment: Unrelated: Don't forget a destructor to `delete [] p;`

Comment: @acraig5075. deliberately removed to keep it compact here. But sure, will add;)

Comment: @RichardCritten. +1, it solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is close to a typo, but my Clang compiler directly stopped on the error with a warning

> unused variable 'p'

in `cArray` ctor.

Let us look at it:

```
cArray(int size)
{
    this -> size = size;       // ok this correctly assign to the member
    T* p = new T[size];        // Oops, this assigns to a local variable...
}
```

The fix is trivial: `p = new T[size];` or if you prefere to make membership more explicit: `this->p = new T[size];`

But beware: you are allocating in the ctor. That means that you should deallocate in destructor, and you should either delete the copy/move ctor/assignment operator or build custom implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor leaves the member `p` uninitialised. When you later read the value and attempt to indirect through it, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

Comment: is overwriting the right terminology? thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Lawhatre right reminology for what? I don't understand the context.

Comment: I first wrote ```T* p;``` and then again declared it inside the constructor ```T* p = new T[size]```. So, I think I have overwritten the variable ```p``` .

Comment: @Lawhatre You have declared a member variable, and within the constructor you've declared a local variable. "Shadowing" is the correct term when a name in an inner scope "shadows" a name in outer scope. Also "hiding".